# How to pass custom url

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, ajax

if we click on button, we want to redirect to this [url](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/customized-mobile-cases/customcase/)
 , we are using below code to pass the url , but we are getting 404 error in [console](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/customized-mobile-cases/)

is this proper way to pass the url ?

```
url="<?php echo Mage::getbaseUrl()?>customized-mobile-cases/customcase/ajax";
```

**complete script**

```
function geturlandredirec()
{  
    var brand=$('brand_select').value;
    var model=$('model_select').value;
    array = [brand, model]; 
    alert(array)
    url="<?php echo Mage::getbaseUrl()?>customized-mobile-cases/customcase/ajax";
    new Ajax.Request(url, {
        method: 'POST',  
        onFailure: function(response){
        },
        parameters: {
            brand: brand,
            model: model
        },
        onSuccess: function(response) { 
            window.location = response.responseText
            return ;
        }
    }); 
}
```

**controller**

```
class Company_Brand_CustomcaseController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    /**
     * Displays the Brand list.
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $breadcrumbs = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs');
        $breadcrumbs->addCrumb('home', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Home'),
            'title' => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Home Page'),
            'link'  => Mage::getBaseUrl()
        ));
        $breadcrumbs->addCrumb('brand', array(
            'label' => $this->__('Brand'),
            'title' => $this->__('Customcase')
        ));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function ajaxAction()
    {
        $brand=$this->getRequest()->getParam('brand');
        $model=$this->getRequest()->getParam('model');
        $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('brand', $brand)
            ->addAttributeToFilter('model', $model);
        $products->getFirstItem();
        echo $_product_url = $products->getProductUrl();
    }
}
```

Comment: Add custom case controller code here

Comment: @PrashantValanda updated the code , please check question.

Comment: use `window.location.href`

Comment: @AmitBera i used this code : `window.location.href = response.responseText` but still its not redirecting to the page

Comment: please add you `config.xml` section rout for this module. and you need call `Mage::getUrl('module_rout/controller/action')` for indexing this url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Ajax call fails. I think there's no product found with parameters you passes (`brand` and `model`).

So use a condition to check if product found OR not :

```
public function ajaxAction()
{
    $brand=$this->getRequest()->getParam('brand');
    $model=$this->getRequest()->getParam('model');
    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('brand', $brand)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('model', $model);

    if($products->getFirstItem()){
        echo $products->getFirstItem()->getProductUrl();
    }
    else {
        echo "false";
    }
}
```

Now check in javascript :

```
....

onSuccess: function(response)
{ 
    if(response.responseText){
        window.location = response.responseText;
    }
}

....
```

Comment: updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

change below code

```
 public function ajaxAction()
{

    $brand=$this->getRequest()->getParam('brand');
    $model=$this->getRequest()->getParam('model');
    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('brand',$brand)->addAttributeToFilter('model',$model);
    $products->getFirstItem();
    echo $_product_url = $products->getProductUrl();



}
```

to:

```
 public function ajaxAction()
{
    $brand=$this->getRequest()->getParam('brand');
    $model=$this->getRequest()->getParam('model');
    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('brand',$brand)->addAttributeToFilter('model',$model);
   $product = $products->getFirstItem();
    echo $_product_url = $product->getProductUrl();
}
```

Comment: now its redirecting to this [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/say-cheese-pink-apple-iphone-6s-phone-case.html) , we wanted to redirect to this [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/customized-mobile-cases/customcase/)

with product name as `selected options` - example : `custom-brand-name-model name`